# Efficient way to replace placeholders in a string using eloquent object

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have an Eloquent class Member with relationships defined as `District`, `Profession`

An instance of `Member` class can be passed to a method which replaces placeholders from a string using this instance.

The placeholders are of format `%placeholder%`, where placeholder can be either an `attribute` of `Member` class or an `attribute` from its relation using dot notation like `%name%`, `%district.name%`

The problem I face is that I get `Member` instance without relations eager loaded.

So I have to reload the instance like this.

```
$member = Member::with(['district', 'profession'])->find($member->id);
```

Then I replace the placeholders using this syntax.

```
$member = $member->toArray();
$placeholders = array_keys($member);
foreach($placeholders as &$placeholder) {
    $placeholder ='%'.$placeholder.'%';
}
$finalString = str_replace($placeholders, array_values($member), $string);
```

Please guide whether I am doing it efficiently or there is some other way to achieve this. Especially I don't want to make another db call to eager load relations so that they can be converted to array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to reload the member. Use `load` to [lazy eager load](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) the relations:

```php
$member->load('district', 'profession');
```